# Call Sitecore.Context.Item in Sitecore Forms with IsAjax checked

Tags: sitecore-forms

Working with Sitecore 9 (update 1) and SXA 1.7.

I am facing an issue related to `Context.Item` in Sitecore Form Save Action. 
In the case of `Web` Database, `Sitecore.Context.Item` is throwing null in Custom Save Action. Is there any way to get the current item in the custom save action? I am using `Sitecore Forms Extension` module by Bart Verdonck.

Also, I don't want to uncheck `Is Ajax` checkbox, it is being used in my form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the js file jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js in the folder 
`\sitecore modules\Web\ExperienceForms\scripts` is different from the out of the box Sitecore and Sitecore extensions.

See here.
https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/tree/master/src/Feature/FormsExtensions/code/sitecore%20modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts

You need to copy back in the js files from the out of the box Sitecore install.

I just submitted a bug request to the forms extension for this. https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions/issues/50

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this issue is only related to any Sitecore forms extension issue. Context item will be null because SaveAction is evaluated in a Ajax call.
I faced with this issue in Sitecore 9.2 and I was able to solve with the following code (item resolving) because Ajax request contains the context page url in the Referer header.

```csharp
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Referer"]) 
     && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"]) 
     && HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"].Equals("XMLHttpRequest"))
{
    var url = new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Referer"]);
    var homePath = Context.Site.StartPath;

    if (!homePath.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        homePath += "/";
    }

    var itemPath = MainUtil.DecodeName(url.AbsolutePath);
    itemPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(itemPath);

    if (itemPath.StartsWith(Context.Site.VirtualFolder))
    {
        itemPath = itemPath.Remove(0, Context.Site.VirtualFolder.Length);
    }

    var pageItem = Context.Site.Database.GetItem(homePath + itemPath);

    return pageItem != null ? pageItem.ID.ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```